# Error while using Scala object in PySpark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am planning to use Scala Object in Pyspark. This is the below code in Scala

```
package za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.utils

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.mutable

object SparkUtils {

  def flattenSchema(df: DataFrame, useShortFieldNames: Boolean = false): DataFrame = {
   val fields = new mutable.ListBuffer[Column]()
   val stringFields = new mutable.ListBuffer[String]()
   val usedNames = new mutable.HashSet[String]()
 }
}
```

Github link : https://github.com/AbsaOSS/cobrix/blob/f95efdcd5f802b903404162313f5663bf5731a83/spark-cobol/src/main/scala/za/co/absa/cobrix/spark/cobol/utils/SparkUtils.scala

I just copied few lines of flattenSchema() method

Spark code in Scala:

```
import za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.utils.SparkUtils
val dfFlattened = SparkUtils.flattenSchema(df)
```

I tried to call same flattenSchema() method in PySpark after importing the jar in spark-submit

```
    dfflatten = DataFrame(sparkContext._jvm.za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.utils.SparkUtils.flattenSchema(df._jdf),sqlContext)
```

But getting error message:

> ```
> df = sparkCont._jvm.za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.utils.SparkUtils.flattenSchema(df._jdf)
> File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p3544.1321029/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
> line 1257, in __call__   File
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p3544.1321029/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
> line 63, in deco   File
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p3544.1321029/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 332, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error
>  occurred while calling
> z:za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.utils.SparkUtils.flattenSchema. Trace:
> py4j.Py4JException: Method flattenSchema([]) does not exist
>     at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
>     at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
>     at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:276)
>     at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>     at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> ```

Please help!

Comment: I think this bug can help you understand what's wrong https://github.com/bartdag/py4j/issues/326

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare the object at Scala so the Python part can find it. Something like this:

```
package za.co.absa.cobrix.spark.cobol.utils

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.mutable

object SparkUtils {
  def flattenSchema(df: DataFrame, useShortFieldNames: Boolean): DataFrame = {
   val fields = new mutable.ListBuffer[Column]()
   val stringFields = new mutable.ListBuffer[String]()
   val usedNames = new mutable.HashSet[String]()
  }
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** Also try not to use method overloading (or default parameters that actually leads to method overloading or other tricks underneath) ... this will be hard to translate (and use it at the Python side).

**NOTE:** to overcome the lack of default values, just pass the value explicitly from Python part and it's done, in this case just an additional boolean. Additionally you may create the default at Python side, it's safer and useful (specially if you have a lot of calling points).

Comment: Hi, Actually the Scala code contains Object declaration but I forgot to copy in the question. I have updated the question and linked the Scala source code github link. Thanks!

Comment: @Arvinth did you try to pass to `flattenSchema` 2 args (df and boolean), not only dataframe?

Comment: @Carlos Before i tried with only with 1 argument(df). Now when i ran with 2 args ( df and bool), its working fine. Thanks a lot!